# Remove Or Add Specific Value in Cell If

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still new to coding & VBA and have a bit of an issue. I have a log for deliveries that I'm working on where I record vendor names, pieces received and pieces returned. I am attempting to append or remove a specific value to a cell with a vendor name I have entered depending on what is entered in to the next two cells in the same row. Here's what I have so far.

```
    Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim d As Variant

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then

       For Each d In Intersect(Target, Range("D:D"))

           If d.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 Or d.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" And 
           Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) <> 0 Then
              d.Offset(0, -2).Value = d.Offset(0, -2).Value + " (Credit)"
           End If

           If d.Offset(0, -1).Value <> 0 Or d.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "" And 
           Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) <> 0 Or Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) = 0 Then
    d.Offset(0, -2).Replace What:=" (Credit)", Replacement:=""
            End If

        Next d

    End If

    End Sub
```

It works at the basic level, if entering from left to right, however, if the value in let's say, Cell C6, is deleted while there is a value entered in to D6, Cell B6 is not updated to include the added value of " (Credit)" to reflect the change.

I am also trying to get it to where if cell B6's value is empty but there is a value in D6, it will not input the added value to B6.

Forgive me if this is confusing. Here's a screengrab of an area.

[Cells B6 to D6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrdwz.jpg)

Comment: Really needs a screenshot or two and the exact rules for editing/clearing cells.  Your code only responds to changes in Column D, so if you need to react to changes in ColB and C you'll also need to add code for those columns.

Comment: I've included a link to a screen grab of an area.

Comment: I'm unclear on what `Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) <> 0` is intended to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Check if the changed cell should start the code
If Target.Row >= 6 And Target.Column >= 3 And Target.Column <= 4 Then

    'Set cells as objects for easier manipulation
    Set Vendor = Cells(Target.Row, 2)
    Set Received = Cells(Target.Row, 3)
    Set Returned = Cells(Target.Row, 4)

    'Check if returned amount is bigger than received
    If Returned > Received Then

        'If so, check if the credit string is already placed
        If InStr(Vendor, " (Credit)") = 0 Then

            'If not, add ir
            Vendor.Value = Vendor & " (Credit)"
        End If

    'If smaller, remove the credit tag
    Else
        Vendor.Value = Replace(Vendor, " (Credit)", "")
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Bechara! This worked flawlessly. Thank you so much for helping!